# Multiply 4 Digit Binary Number By 3 - Circuit

Tags: multiplier, carry-look-ahead

I want to find a way to multiply a 4 digit binary number by 3.

I have this circuit that doing this process and I don't understand how it works.

To multiply a number by 2 I need to shift the digits to the left and if I want to multiply by 3 I will have to shift it by and then add the original number

[image: ripple carry adder]

I would like to get some explanation how its doing the process I wrote before.

Comment: Shifting to the right divides by two! Shifting by one and adding one doesn't multiply by three!

Comment: @LeonHeller: Red herring in this case; there's simply no point in using extra circuitry to add `0` to a binary value.

Comment: @LeonHeller fixed that, its was my mistake.

Comment: 3 is 2 + 1, so you need to multiply the 4 bit number by 2 (producing a 5 bit number) and then add the original 4 bit number to it. e.g 1011 - shift left 10110 (x2) and then add to the original value -> 100001

Answer (score 3):

The circuit is performing the middle addition in long multiplication:

```
    WXYZ
 *    11
 -------
    WXYZ
 + WXYZ0
 -------
(result)
```